# Giving user the option to navigate through a file system in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, svn

I needed help in knowing how to navigate through a file system using a batch file.

At the moment my code looks like this :

```
echo ============================================================  
echo This batch file will automate opening a workspace in eclipse 
echo ============================================================  %NL%


set svnbin="C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svn.exe"
set svnroot= some_svn_link 

%svnbin% list %svnroot%> projects.txt

type projects.txt

echo ============================================================%NL%  
set /p checkout="Enter project name to checkout="

set svnfolder= %svnroot% / %checkout% /trunk/ 
set CheckOutLocation=C:\Users\user_name\workspace\
```

At the moment when the batch file is run, the user sees the list of files since it is copied in projects.txt and i am typing it on the standard output. 
How can I replace the use of saving this txt file and make it more functional by giving the user the choice of navigation through dir ?

Thanks

Comment: Batch-files don't have means to interactively select the file/folder, so what about the usual and convenient method of adding a command to right click context menu of a directory via `HKCR\Directory\shell`?

Comment: If you need to navigate through a file system then there are scripts to do that also - not plain batch but ones that are scriptable in batch files.

Answer (score 0):

This menu picker was written by Aacini and can be used to select files.

I modified the section below to look for .txt files in the current directory and it should do what you require very well.

```
rem Define the options
set numOpts=0
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   set /A numOpts+=1
   set "option[!numOpts!]=%%a"
)
```

This is the original code

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Multi-line menu with options selection via DOSKEY
rem Antonio Perez Ayala


rem The creation of a multi-line menu that allows to select options via arrow keys has been an old request in Batch files. This type of selection menu may be developed with the aid of auxiliary programs, like GetKey to get the selection keys and a combination of CursorPos/ColorShow to deselect the current option and highlight the new one; however, such a program is somewhat complex.
rem 
rem I devised a simpler method to achieve such selection menu using DOSKEY program. This DOS command store the lines executed in the command-line (like inputs to SET /P command) and store they in a history that may be displayed in the form of a selection menu when F7 key is pressed. This way, the method consist in:
rem 
rem     Clear previous DOSKEY history.
rem     Execute several SET /P commands that read the menu options, so the DOSKEY history is filled with them.
rem     Send a F7 key to the keyboard.
rem     Execute a SET /P "OPTION=Prompt: "; the input to this command will be completed via the selection menu of DOSKEY.
rem
rem There is a strange point about this program: the DOSKEY /REINSTALL command clear the history only when it is executed the first time. If previous program is executed a second time in the same cmd.exe session, the DOSKEY history is not cleared, so menu options are wrong. I read DOSKEY documentation in Microsoft and SS64 sites and didn't found any reference about this problem. I tested this program in Windows 8, so I don't know if this problem also appear in other versions...
rem 
rem Antonio



rem Define the options
set numOpts=0
for %%a in (First Second Third Fourth Fifth) do (
   set /A numOpts+=1
   set "option[!numOpts!]=%%a Option"
)
set /A numOpts+=1
set "option[!numOpts!]=exit"

rem Clear previous doskey history
doskey /REINSTALL
rem Fill doskey history with menu options
cscript //nologo /E:JScript "%~F0" EnterOpts
for /L %%i in (1,1,%numOpts%) do set /P "var="

:nextOpt
cls
echo MULTI-LINE MENU WITH OPTIONS SELECTION
echo/
rem Send a F7 key to open the selection menu
cscript //nologo /E:JScript "%~F0"
set /P "var=Select the desired option: "
echo/
if "%var%" equ "exit" goto :EOF
echo Option selected: "%var%"
pause
goto nextOpt


@end

var wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"),
    envVar = wshShell.Environment("Process"),
    numOpts = parseInt(envVar("numOpts"));

if ( WScript.Arguments.Length ) {
   // Enter menu options
   for ( var i=1; i <= numOpts; i++ ) {
      wshShell.SendKeys(envVar("option["+i+"]")+"{ENTER}");
   }
} else {
   // Enter a F7 to open the menu
   wshShell.SendKeys("{F7}");
}
```